# Stop() function not functioning as desired in MediaPlayer :Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I implemented stop fucntionality in MediaPlayer for Android but unfortunately is working as pause whenever I press that play function, its starts from the place where it was stopped not from start. Here is the code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.stop:
            mp.stop();
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.play:

            mp.start();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

What could be the possible reason for this and how to correct it ?

Comment: Quick note on your code. It is not such a good idea to call prepare() in your UI thread. Also prepare is usually called before start() not after stop()

Answer (score 0):

`mp.seekTo(0)` will start it from the beginning. After stopping or before starting, you can call this method.

Comment: is this the way stop() works , that whenever we call play after play it would begin from where it left ?